# element in field, not a square

Tags: field-theory

I am doing a specific exercise where the quaternion group is realised as a Galois group of some field extension. It goes like this: let $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$ and $\alpha = (2 +\sqrt 2)(3 +\sqrt 6)$. I want to show that $\alpha$ is not a square in $K$. I tried to solve equations explicitly to derive some contradiction but I didn't succeed. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That extension has degree 4, so the Galois group cannot be the Quaternion group.

Comment: I didn't say the quaternion group is obtained as $G(K/\mathbb Q)$ (this group is just the Klein four-group). But after proving that $\alpha$ is not a square you can adjunct the square root of $\alpha$ to $K$ in order to get a field extension $L/\mathbb Q$ with $G(L/\mathbb Q)$ equal to the quaternion group.

Comment: Ah, it's good to say your strategy:  it was not obvious from your characterization.